# jQuery using delay() with $.each() not working

Tags: jquery, delay, each

I have different classes each with a different background. I'm trying to switch background on div #elm every 2 seconds. Why is the following not delaying 2 seconds between each index. They all come in at once.

```
var classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];
$.each(classes, function(index, val) {
    $('#elm').removeAttr('class').addClass(val).delay(2000*index);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLHqP/

Comment: `delay` is for the effects queue and won't work for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delay()` only works on effects.

**From jQuery [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) documantation**

> The .delay() method is best for
>   delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it
>   doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a
>   replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more
>   appropriate for certain use cases.

Since `addClass()` is not an effect, you can include a fadeIn() effect and use addclass as a callback function.

```
var classes = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];
$.each(classes, function(index, ui) {
    $('body').removeAttr('class').delay(1000).fadeIn(function() {
        $(this).addClass(ui);
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/8e3Rm/

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT:

this works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    setTimeout (    
        (function(index){
        return function(){
            $('#elm').removeAttr('class').addClass(classes[index]);
        };
        })(i), 2000*i);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. No need to post a self executing function in each(). Check the jsfiddle example i posted in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the delay method only for events that use the effects queue, like fading in and out, etc.?